# ODBC driver on Unix for MS Excel?

Tags: java, perl, xlsb

Does anyone know whether there is an ODBC driver for Unix ,out there (free or commercial) that connects to MS Excel files?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.unixodbc.org I'm sure you'll find what you want through there.  Good Luck

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your comment, but seems this organization http://www.unixodbc.org don’t support excel driver, as I have searched.